# Why is it necessary to show subsequence convergence in the extreme value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I’m probably making this more complicated than it needs to be, but I’m trying to figure out why it is necessary to prove the convergence of a subsequence in proving the extreme value theorem (EVT).  I typically see the EVT  proved as follows:

Given an interval $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:

- 1) prove that the sequence  $f(x_n)$ converges to the supremum of the set $S=\{f:[a,b]\}$.
- 2) prove that a subseqeunce $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x_{0})$, and since a subsequence of a convergent sequence must converge to the same limit, then that means that $f(x_{0})=\sup S$.

Why is the second bullet point necessary, if we already proved that $f$ attains the supremum?

Comment: The first bullet point doesn't say that $f$ attains the supremum, it only says that there is a sequence $x_n$ so that $f(x_n)$ approaches the supremum.  You still have to prove that there is a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ with $f(x_0) = \sup f$.

Comment: In general, if your interval is not closed, for example, the sequence $x_n$ may not converge in your interval. $x_n = 1-1/n$ for $f(x) = x$ on the interval $(0,1)$.  You have to somehow 'trap' a limit point of your sequence so it doesn't escape.

Comment: Or, even if the interval is closed $x_n$ might still not converge - e.g. if $f$ has more than one maximizing point and $x_n$ alternates between which it gets close to.  Thus you'll have to pick a subsequence that converges to one $x$ in particular.

Comment: - Let me make sure I understand what you’re saying.  1) So what you’re saying is that “converges to the supremum” and a the function value actually equaling the supremum are NOT at all the same thing, right?  Because the proof here explicitly does say “converges to the supremum”: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_extreme_value_theorem.  2) But then you’re also saying that closedness of the interval is insufficient to show this?

Comment: Finally, you’re ALSO saying that that only way to show that the supremum and the function value are equal is to show three things:  the limit of $f(x_n)$ equals the supremum, the domain of $f$ is closed, and there’s a subsequence that ALSO converges to the supremum.  Is it true that all three are required?

Comment: For 1), yes, the issue is that even though $f(x_n)$ converges to the supremum that doesn't tell you that $x_n$ converges.

Comment: For the second question, yes, all three are required.  But I don't quite think of it as "proving the supremum and the function value are equal" - it is an existence proof.  You can't prove $\sup f = f(x)$ until you have defined what $x$ is.  I would put it as "showing that $f$ attains its supremum at a particular input $x$."

Comment: Note that other important requirements are that $f$ is continuous, and that the interval is bounded.

Comment: But why do we care that $x_n$ converges?  The theorem is about $f(x_n)$.  IN the first paragraph of the link that I shared, we've already proven that $f(x_n)$ converges to $M$, so why is it at all necessary to say anything about $x_n$?

Comment: What is the statement of the EVT you are working with? The extreme value theorem states that a continuous $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ attains a maximum (and minimum).  The definition of *attains a maximum* means that "there exists an $x$ so that $f(y) \leq f(x)$ for all $y \in [a,b]$."  Hence, the goal is to find such a value $x \in [a,b]$ somehow.

Comment: got it! There are several things I missed here.  First, we provethat the function $f(x_0)=\sup S$ at some point x_0.  Then, as you said “until you have defined what  is”, this statement only makes sense if we say what x_0 is.  So, then we need to say what x_0 we’re talking about.  So next we show that there’s a subsequence x_n_k that converges to some x’ because the x’s are bounded.  Then, since f is continuous, the limit of $f(x_n_k) = f(lim x_n_k)$.  Finally, we connect these two informations by saying the subsequence and the sequence must converge to the same thing.  So $s=f(x’)= f(x_0)$.

Comment: "First, we prove that the function $f(x_0) =\sup S$ at some point $x_0$" - no, that's whole thing we're trying to prove.  The first thing is to construct a sequence $x_n$ with $f(x_n) \rightarrow \sup S$.

Comment: Okay, yes my bad it should be $f(x_n) \rightarrow \sup S$.  But then is the rest of my explanation correct?

Comment: Basically right, yup!  Although you need the interval to be closed to make sure the limiting value is in your set.

Comment: Right, if the set $[a,b]$ were not closed, then we could *still* say that $x_n_k \rightarrow x'$.  But it might still be such that $x_{n_k}$ never equals $x'$

Comment: Even if the interval is closed closed it may be that $x_{n_k} != x'$ for all $k$ where $x' = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k}$.  But since $[a,b]$ is closed we know that $x' \in [a,b]$.  (if the interval was not closed, e.g., $[a,b)$, then $x_{n_k} \rightarrow b \notin [a,b)$ is possible.)

Comment: Okay, that actually makes sense.  Because basically we say that $x'$ (the limit point of the subsequence $x_{n_k}$) is inside $[a,b]$,  which...we eventually connect to implying that $f(x_{n_k})$ actually *reaches* the ponit $f(x')$ where the function equals the supremum.

Comment: Furthermore, the reason we cannot make the same argument for the codomain of $f$ is because we know that the domain is both 1) closed and 2) bounded, whereas for the codomain we only know that it is bounded, but we don't know if it is closed.